# MongoError: must have $meta projection for all $meta sort keys using Mongo DB Native NodeJS Driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-search, node-mongodb-native

Running the following text search directly on MongoDB results in no issues:

```
db.getCollection('schools').find({
  $text:
    {
      $search: 'some query string',
      $caseSensitive: false,
      $diacriticSensitive: true
    }
}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})
```

However when trying to run the same query using the [native NodeJS driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb):

```
function getSchools(filter) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:60001', function(err, client) {
      const collection = client.db('schools').collection('schools');

      collection.find({
        $text:
          {
            $search: filter,
            $caseSensitive: false,
            $diacriticSensitive: true
          }
        }, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        if (err) return reject(err);

        resolve(docs);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
MongoError: must have $meta projection for all $meta sort keys
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

OK, according to [this bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1265) since the version 3.0.0 `find` and `findOne` [no longer support](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/3.0.0/CHANGES_3.0.0.md#find) the `fields` parameter and the query needs to be rewritten as follows:

```
collection.find({
        $text:
          {
            $search: filter,
            $caseSensitive: false,
            $diacriticSensitive: true
          }
        })
        .project({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
        .sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})
```

Comment: find documentation here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#find

Comment: So why don't they update the [textScore sort example in their very own documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#sort-by-text-search-score) accordingly?! :rolleyes: Thanks for pointing this out! Probably saved me quite some time, especially because the error message doesn't give a very good hint to the actual error...

Comment: Hi can anyone tell me if I had to sort in reverse order of the same query?

Comment: @Christallkeks because those are the docs for the mongo shell, the nodejs driver docs are [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#find)

Answer (score 4):

In the current version of the native MongoDB driver, you need to include the [`projection` key among the options for `find`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#find):

```js
const results = await collection.find(
  {
    $text: { $search: filter }
  },
  {
    projection: { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } },
    sort: { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } },
  }
).toArray();
```